# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near '#'

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, between

```
UPDATE tblAlbum
SET    dateAlbumReleaseDate = '12/1/2003'
WHERE  dateAlbumReleaseDate BETWEEN #6/1/2002# AND #11/31/2002#
       AND IngAlbumID IN (SELECT a.IngAlbumID
                          FROM   tblAlbum a,
                                 tblArtist ar,
                                 tblLINKArtist_Album al
                          WHERE  a.IngAlbumID = al.IngAlbumID
                                 AND al.IngArtistID = ar.IngArtisID
                                 AND ar.strArtistName = ( 'Oasis' ))
```

Comment: If you define dates in string format in SQL Server, you should use the ISO-8601 format `YYYYMMDD` to be safe from any regional/language settings. Try `WHERE dateAlbumReleaseDate BETWEEN '20020601' AND '20021130'` for instance - don't use `#` for your dates in SQL Server / T-SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE tblAlbum
SET    dateAlbumReleaseDate = '12/1/2003'
WHERE  dateAlbumReleaseDate BETWEEN '6/1/2002' AND '11/31/2002'
   AND IngAlbumID IN (SELECT a.IngAlbumID
                      FROM   tblAlbum a,
                             tblArtist ar,
                             tblLINKArtist_Album al
                      WHERE  a.IngAlbumID = al.IngAlbumID
                             AND al.IngArtistID = ar.IngArtisID
                             AND ar.strArtistName = ( 'Oasis' ))
```

I hope this is what you expected.